# Naming convention for CFBundleSignature and CFBundleIdentifier

Tags: macos, cfbundleidentifier

I am wondering how do I know what name I should give for my CFBundleSignature and CFBundleIdentifier.  I believe these are supposed to be unique identifier so do I have to somehow get these names from apple?  Say my app is called javaapp and comes from the website javaapp.  Should my CFBundleIdentifier be com.javaapp.javaapp?  What 4 letters should I use for my CFBundleSignature?

Answer (score 28):

The Bundle Identifier uniquely identifies your application.  If you have registered a domain name, use that.  Otherwise, just use `com.<your name>.<application name>`

The Bundle Signature is analogous to the "Creator Code" found in Classic Mac OS.  It exists only for compatibility with Classic Mac OS apps and documents.  Modern Mac OS X apps don't need to worry about assigning a Bundle Signature.

Comment: Can I use four segments? e.g. com.companyname.divisionname.appname

Comment: You can have any number of segments.  For example: com.apple.iWork.Pages

Comment: You say "If you have registered a domain name, use that" - but do we use the domain name or the inversed notation like net.mydomainNameBeforeDot.unnecessaryExtraPartThatIWouldLoveToOmit?

Comment: obviously the inverse notation

Answer (score 15):

Yes, assuming that you own the domain name javaapp.com, com.javaapp.javaapp would be fine as a bundle ID.  There are some rules; as I recall, the bundle ID parts can only contain letters, digits, and hyphens.

The bundle signature in new Xcode projects is initialized as ????.  Apple used to have a web page where you could register a unique bundle signature (AKA creator code) but I can no longer find it, so I would assume that the concept is obsolete.

Comment: The link above is now broken, I'd like to know where to go instead.

Comment: @MMazzon I can't find that page either, so I assume it's just gone.  I've updated my answer accordingly.